# How do i count the number of times a pattern has occurred in a dataset in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I would like to count how many occurrences of starting patterns has occurred in a dataset in t-sql.

Something that will result in something like this:

'abc%' 2
'axd%' 3
'dfj%' 1

from data:

String column:

abcdfjhs
abckgdhsa

axdgahk
axddrds
axdfgd

dfjgkj

Answer (score 2):

You could try aggregating based on the three leftmost characters in the column:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(col, 3) + '%' AS prefix,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    LEFT(col, 3);
```

[image]

### Demo